# my custom material colors not working in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I have a jetpack compose project that I defiend my custom Material theme there like below:

```
val myLightPrimary = Color(0xFF825500)
val myLightOnPrimary = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
val myLightSecondary = Color(0xFF6F5B40)
val myLightOnSecondary = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)

val myDarkPrimary = Color(0xFFFFB945)
val myDarkOnPrimary = Color(0xFF452B00)
val myDarkSecondary = Color(0xFFDDC3A2)
val myDarkOnSecondary = Color(0xFF3E2E16)

private val myDarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = myDarkPrimary,
    onPrimary = myDarkOnPrimary,
    secondary = myDarkSecondary,
    onSecondary = myDarkOnSecondary,
)

private val myLightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = myLightPrimary,
    onPrimary = myLightOnPrimary,
    secondary = myLightSecondary,
    onSecondary = myLightOnSecondary
)

@Composable
fun MyTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val replyColorScheme = when {
        darkTheme -> myDarkColorScheme
        else -> myLightColorScheme
    }
    

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = myColorScheme,
        typography = myTypography,
        shapes = shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

and I use this theme in the `setContent` like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            myTheme {
                LoginScreen()
            }
        }
    }
```

Now inside the `loginScreen` when I want to use `MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary` its not my primary color that I defiend above.

```
OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                label = { Text(text = "username") },
                value = username.value,
                onValueChange = { username.value = it },
                textStyle = TextStyle(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
            )
```

I think that this color is purple color that is there by default even though I deleted 'colors.xml` from my resources. I am very confused ...

Comment: Declared `val replyColorScheme = ...` passed `colorScheme = myColorScheme`. What is `myColorScheme`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a typo: "myTheme {LoginScreen()}" should be "MyTheme {LoginScreen()}".

Not sure why it's not flagged as an error though.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        var darkMode by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        myTheme(darkTheme = darkMode) {
            LoginScreen(isDarkMode = { darkMode != darkMode })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the MyTheme Composable:

```
MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = replyColorScheme ,
    typography = myTypography,
    shapes = shapes,
    content = content
)
```

Inside the onCreate Function:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyTheme {
            LoginScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).